# How to returns the array of DOM nodes in google map V3 api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How to returns the array of DOM nodes that hold the content of the tabs of this info window in google map V3 api?

I am migrating the google map version from **v2** to **v3**. In **V2** they are using these type of codes to get the array of DOM nodes that hold the content of the tabs of this info window. The below code is google map v2 code.

```
if (!div) return;
var link = div.down('a.jsDetailsLink');
if (!link) return;
link.href = '/ajax/?action=profileInfoFull&id=' + location.id;
new Facebox(link);
```

how to use in V3, to get the [Object HTMLDivElement]? Please help.!!

Comment: I haven't used google maps api2 but I have used api3. Could you please explain what you are trying to do so I can be of assistance?

Comment: **Click on the marker in google map, through Ajax call load the content in Infowindow. In that infowindow contains the following code for the link.Find below code**, <a class="jsDetailsLink" href="/profile/id/name">More info</a>} **I want to change the href value. For that We have tried infowindow.getContent() it returns only the string format with html content. So we can’t change the exact href value. Instead of string format with html content, return with [Object HTMLDivElement] easily can change the URL. With the above JS code.From that link, it will open another popup through facebox.**

Comment: Well if getContent() method didn't do what you want, you could check the dom from the console and see the markup of the infowindow. It must have some classes that make it distinguishable. Then you can use jquery to get it.